# How do I add logic to a sorted array delete algorithm to account for a "node not found" scenario?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I was assigned to write a delete algorithm for my sorted array structure.  It continues to be a source of problems for my program because, in certain instances, it is completing the delete when it should be returning False for "node not found".  So the delete function works, but it does it even when the node is not found.  Where is the flaw in my logic?

```
    public boolean delete(String targetListing)
    {
        int low = 0;
        int high = next - 1;
        int i = (low + high) / 2;

        //check to see if target listing is the same as the current node key field
        while(data[i].getName().compareToIgnoreCase(targetListing) != 0 && high != low)   
        {
            if(data[i].getName().compareToIgnoreCase(targetListing) >= 1)
            {
                high = i - 1; //eliminate the bottom of the array
            }
            else
            {
                low = i + 1; //eliminate the top of the array
            }

            i = (low + high) / 2;  
        }
        //this is my logic to determine if the node was found or not
        //I also tried if(low == high) but sometimes that would be true at the 
        //at the position that the node was found      
        if(i == next || i < 0)
        {
            return false; //node not found
        }

        for(int j = i; j < next - 1; j++)
        {
            data[j] = data[j + 1];
        }

        next = next - 1;
        data[next] = null;
        return true;//node found and deleted
```

If anyone could also point me to a good example of a sorted array delete algorithm that accounts for a node not found scenario I would really appreciate it.  I would have thought that would be a very easy thing to find, but I am having a hard time finding it.

Comment: It should be fairly easy to find the problem with debugging or working through what your function does with an example with pen and paper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest answer: Replace your `if(i == next || i < 0)` with `if(data[i].getName().compareToIgnoreCase(targetListing) != 0)` -- in other words, check that you've actually found a match rather than simply having narrowed down to a single possibility.